# find point on a line segment to form right triangle?

Tags: math, geometry

Given a line segment from **A** (10, 100) to **B** (300, 300);

and then point **A'** (10, 200) where **A'** has the *same x*, but a *different y*, as **A**, how do I find the point where a line from **A'** would intersect the line **AB** at **D** so that **A**, **A'**, and **D** form a right triangle?

[image: illustration of the problem]

Comment: So you just want to compute the *y*-coordinate of a point on the line given its *x*-coordinate? Well, use the line euqation and put in the *x*.

Comment: If the line is given by y = mx+b, solving for x gives x = (y-b)/m.  Just find the slope (m) and the y-intercept (b) of the original line and plug it into the equation where y = 200.  This is from high school level Algebra I.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the equation for the line and substitute in the y you already have.

Comment: thank you.  it would be helpful to me to see how this would be implemented in my example.